# Append two 2D arrays without use of the Java arrays class

Tags: java, arrays, append, concatenation, cell

I'm confused on how to make a java method to append two different 2D arrays without using/importing the arrays class. This is what I have so far:

```
private Cell[][] appendArrays(Cell[][] first, Cell[][] second) {
    Cell[][] third = new Cell[first.length][first[0].length + second[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < first[i].length; j++) {
            third[i][j] = first[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < second.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < second[i].length; j++) {
            // don't know what to do here
        }
    }
    return third;
}
```

A Cell is just an object, but I'm trying to understand the logic behind appending arrays so any help would be appreciated!

Also, I know there is a similar question found here ([How do you append two 2D array in java properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820905/how-do-you-append-two-2d-array-in-java-properly)), but the answer is given on appending arrays from the top down (given both parameter arrays have the same amount of columns), while I am looking for appending arrays from side to side (assuming both parameter arrays have the same amount of rows).

Comment: ```third[i][first[0].length + j] = second[i][j];```

Comment: Something like `third[ first.length + i ][ first[0].length + j ] = second[i][j]`? You also assume that `first[X].length` is the same for all `X` (and the same for `second[X]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  I think something like this is what you're looking for.

```
private Cell[][] appendArrays(Cell[][] first, Cell[][] second) {
    Cell[][] third = new Cell[first.length][first[0].length + second[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < first[i].length; j++) {
            third[i][j] = first[i][j];
        }
        for (int j = first[i].length; j < first[i].length + second[i].length; j++) {
            third[i][j] = second[i][j-first[i].length];
        }
    }
    return third;
}
```